# React / DRF: How to handle Many to Many relationship in POST request?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

How do I make sure that Many-To-Many relationships are considered in my POST-request to a Django Rest Framework API?

I have the following models:

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name="blogs")
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="blogs", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="blogs")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I am making the request like:

**Frontend (don't mind the missing brackets)**

```
const addContent = (content) => {
    axiosInstance
      .post(`/content/blogs/`, content, tokenConfig(auth.token))
      .then((res) => {
        dispatchMessages(
          createMessage({ contentAdded: "Submitted successfully" })
        );
```

The content object I am passing in looks like:

```
const content = {
      name: "content title",
      description: "content description",
      url: "content URL",
      tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    };
```

The POST request itself is going through and all the fields are posted correctly except for the tags, which appear empty.

**Example Response:**

```
 {
        "id": 2,
        "tags": [],
        "name": "Blog #1",
        "description": "Its the best",
        "url": "https://website.com",

    },
```

My serializer looks like:

**serializers.py**

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field="name")
    owner = CustomOwnerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = "__all__"
```

And the viewset:

**api.py**

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.all()
```

Thank you for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have done all the tedious work. The only thing that is not allowing the tags to get saved is the `read_only=True` in the `SlugRelatedField` argument. This argument ignores the field when it is posted. So you have to remove `read_only=True` so that tags get parsed. I would go a little further and add `queryset` in the slugrelatedfield as `queryset=Tags.objects.all()`

This would only work if you have already created tags in your db and then you add the same names in your list. If you want to create them dynamically when you post them you have to modify the default create method in your serializer([check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599499/non-trivial-django-serializer-for-a-complex-model/57645352#57645352))